# How to start another asynchronous stream after a disposed rx stream?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

In my observable I have the following stream

```java
Observable
  .empty()
  .concatWith(longOperationA)
  .doOnDispose(() -> {
    Log.d("tag", Thread.currentThread().getName()); // == main
  })
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(mySubscriber);
```

**Is there any way to start another asynchronous operation in the `doOnDisposed()` method?**